# Can I insert 3rd party marketing tags that use document.write() into Google Tag Manager (GTM)?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-tag-manager

I'm installing 3rd party marketing tags into my GTM (v2) container. The tags are a real nuisance, making heavy use of `document.write`. Though Google Tag Manager claims to support `document.write`, these tags throw javascript errors when fired. Here's an example of such a tag.

```
<script src="http://ib.adnxs.com/seg?add=1958353,6039160&t=1" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

This script `seg?add=1958353,6039160&t=1` goes on to call `document.write` twice:

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://js.b1js.com/tagcontainer.js?id=110386891486949186&type=1"></scr'+'ipt>');
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="http://cdn.adnxs.com/ib/async_usersync.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

If I ask GTM to support `document.write` for this tag, and set the tag to fire on all pages, I'll get an error on page load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
Uncaught #<Object>
```

If I uncheck GTM's "support `document.write`" for this tag, I'll get this as a warning in my console:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

I've tried deferring tag firing until after DOM Ready, which worked for another one of my tags, but not this one.

I have at least 3 tags that are configured to use `document.write` in this way, and all throw the same error when fired. Please understand that other tags that don't rely on `document.write` work perfectly well. Thank you for any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: The bizarre thing is that those document.writes insert scripts that load other scripts asynchronously.  Both scripts look for the first script tag in your page an try to insert their own script tags before that (that's the point where the scripts look for the parent nodes). As a test you might dispense with the document.writes and use a custom HTML tag to write out the script tags directly, just to see if the error persists without the document.write). GTM supports document.write so this should not be an issue, it's more likely that there is a problem with the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it help, but try to set the firing rule as gtm.load instead of DOM ready.